# Web Scraping: xmlHTTP GET request not working

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, msxml2

I am trying to scrape flashscore.com with VBA using XMLHTTP request. It is making multiple javascript based requests to the server. One request i am interested in (as visible in the chrome developer tools) is this:

[image]

but when I send the request, it fails. The code is

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
     .Open "GET", "https://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/f_1_0_5_en_1", False
     .send
End With
```

Can anybody guide me why i can not retrieve the content like this? Why the request is failing? Thanks